# Golang http client always performs get requests and does not post

Tags: json, http, go, post, get

I'm currently experiencing a problem that really frustrates me and where i absolutely can't see anny issues with my code.

What i'm trying to achieve is to send a http POST message to a mockup of an iDrac i wrote (both softwares written in golang) to control the mockup's powerstate, but no matter what i configure for the request, the mockup always receives get requests with an empty body.

The function i create and send the request with:

```golang
func (iDrac *IDrac) SetPowerstate(powerstate string) error {

    //Create reset type json string
    var jsonStr = `{"ResetType":"` + powerstate + `"}`

    //Create the request with auth header
    req, reqErr := iDrac.buildHttpRequestWithAuthorizationHeader(http.MethodPost, "https://"+iDrac.hostAddress+apiBaseURL+apiChassisURL+apiChassisResetAction, jsonStr)
    if reqErr != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("COULD_NOT_CREATE_REQUEST: " + reqErr.Error())
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

    //Make the request
    resp, doErr := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if doErr != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("COULD_NOT_SEND_POST_REQUEST_TO_IDRAC_API" + doErr.Error())
    }

    //Check if the request was successful
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        return fmt.Errorf("COULD_NOT_CHANGE_SERVER_POWER_STATUS_OVER_IDRAC HTTP:" + resp.Status)
    }

    return nil
}
```

The helper function i use to build the request with:

```golang
func (iDrac *IDrac) buildHttpRequestWithAuthorizationHeader(method string, url string, content string) (*http.Request, error) {

    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(content)))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+iDrac.hashedCredentials)
    return req, nil
}
```

And finally the function where the mockup proccesses the request:

```golang
func handlePerformReset(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    garbagelog.Log("Handling reset perform request from " + r.RemoteAddr)

    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        garbagelog.Log("Invalid http method! Got " + r.Method + " expected POST")
        w.WriteHeader(405)
        return
    }
    if !checkAuthorization(r.BasicAuth()) {
        w.WriteHeader(401)
        return
    }

    var resetType nidrac.ResetType
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&resetType)
    if err != nil {
        garbagelog.Log("Could not decode reset type: " + err.Error())
        w.WriteHeader(422)
        return
    }

    iDracMock.PerformResetAction(resetType.ResetType)
    garbagelog.Log(">>>>SEVERSTATE: " + iDracMock.PowerState().PowerState + "<<<<")

    w.WriteHeader(200)
}
```

The type the iDrac mock tries to convert the body to:

```golang
type ResetType struct {
    ResetType string
}
```

It works flawlessly when i try to reach the endpoint with postman:
[iDrac mockup log confirming the successful request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXa2h.png)

Postnam request configuration:
[Postman request configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t58qi.png)

But it somehow does not work when i try making the request with go code:
[iDrac mockup log saying that the http method is invalid (because it's get instead of post)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gxm1.png)

I spent two hours trying to find a solution but i somehow did not find a post with someone having the same problem that i have.

Edit: Corrected old code. The problem remains even with the silly mistake fixed:

```golang
//Create the request with auth header
    req, reqErr := iDrac.buildHttpRequestWithAuthorizationHeader(http.MethodPost, "https://"+iDrac.hostAddress+apiBaseURL+apiChassisURL+apiChassisResetAction, jsonStr)
    if reqErr != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("COULD_NOT_CREATE_REQUEST: " + reqErr.Error())
    }
```

How i build the routes in the iDrac mockup:

```golang
http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(handleDefault))
    http.Handle("/reset", http.HandlerFunc(handleReset))
    http.Handle("/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1", http.HandlerFunc(handlePowerStateGet))
    http.Handle("/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1/Actions/ComputerSystem.Reset", http.HandlerFunc(handlePerformReset))

    garbagelog.Log("Starting webserver")
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", currentConfig.CertFile, currentConfig.PrivKeyFile, nil)
    if err != nil {
        garbagelog.Log("Could not serve TLS: " + err.Error())
    }
```

In both requests, the one created in my iDrac comms module and the one received by the iDrac mockup, did confirm that the requested path is:

> r.URL.Path = /redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1/Actions/ComputerSystem.Reset

Comment: Show how you build your routes. Also log `r.URL.Path` to confirm the requested path. Looks like there is a trailing slash.

Comment: @Philidor added the info at the bottom of my question. The requested paths do match as far as i can tell...

Comment: Can you remove dots from the routes and trying again?

Comment: @Philidor having no dots did not change anything, sadly. This would not have been an option anyway, because i made the mockup to only test my iDrac communications module with and the real redfish iDrac API it should communicate later sadly requires the dots in the routes...

Comment: The root of the problem can be in the route handling by the default hrrp module. dot in the path segments "." and "..", also known as dot-segments, are defined for relative reference within the path name hierarchy.

Comment: @Philidor The thing is that the request arrives at the correct api endpoint and i personally can not see why the route should affect the used http method. In the end, i rarely work with http so i can't really tell...

Comment: Another things here is looks like the `/` root route catch all requests. What is inside `handleDefault`  handler?

Comment: Consider to use https://github.com/gorilla/mux toolkit 
It has a much better routing.

Comment: @Philidor thank you for your input. I already found the problem and it was very silly. Have a look at the solution i posted. - Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem:

The constants i built the urls with were defined like this:

```golang
const (
    apiBaseURL            = "/redfish/v1/"
    apiChassisURL         = "/Systems/System.Embedded.1"
    apiChassisResetAction = "/Actions/ComputerSystem.Reset"
)
```

Leading to a url that looks like this:

> `https://host/redfish/v1//Systems/System.Embedded.1/Actions/ComputerSystem.Reset`
> (Notice the double // between v1 and Systems)

So i've fixed it:

```golang
const (
    apiBaseURL            = "/redfish/v1"
    apiChassisURL         = "/Systems/System.Embedded.1"
    apiChassisResetAction = "/Actions/ComputerSystem.Reset"
)
```

And everything works correctly:
[Test results showing that every test was successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlI8S.png)

I thank everyone for their input for helping me not lose my mind completely.

Answer (score 1):

based on your screenshot, I can see you are using a "POST" request in your postman, but in your code is "GET".

I think nothing wrong with the code but the method only :)

Comment: Well that was just plainly stupid from me. I corrected that error before but discarded my changes before i posted this question, not thinking about this error coming back. I corrected the code in that regard but the problem sadly still remains.

Comment: It's a kind of mistake certainly everyone has made. Perhaps not published to SO, but anyway. You shouldn't call yourself stupid for that.

Comment: Yeah, it sometimes happens inside the code-based bro @HighQualityWaschbaer. Can you share me the latest code that you are having the issue?